# Return a Person ID only when a second sublevel table meets a criteria for its values in a column

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql

TSQL

I have a *Person* table with a column 'Id', a *CourtCase* table with a column 'Id', and a *Bond* table with columns 'Id' and 'isReleased'.  *Person* can have many *CourtCase* records and *CourtCase* can have many *Bond* records.  I am wanting to count only PersonIDs that have cases in which all *Bond* records belonging to that *Case* have *Bond* columns that are ALL *isReleased = true*.  Meaning a Case is not bond released unless all bonds for that case are released.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Result = 
    Persons.Where(p=>p.Cases.All(q=>q.Bonds.All(w=>w.isReleased))).Count()
```